# Angular 6 readonly textarea won't bind from second textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Using Angular 6 and Material controls, I'm displaying my data (string array) in a read only text area.  I have a second editable text area, in which I want to enter text and then using a button, have the text from the second area added dynamically to the (first) read only text area.

I've also tried one-way binding and interpolation.  When debugging, I can see that my new text is pushed to the data string array.  Regardless, the updated string array is not displayed in the first text area.

```js
this.comments: string[];
this.newComment: string;

this.comments = data;
this.newComment = '';

addNewComment(newComment: string) {
    if (newComment.length > 0) {
        this.comments.push(newComment + '\n');
        this.newComment = '';
        this.saModified = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <textarea matInput id='newComment' name='newComment' [disabled]="!userHasRole('Admin')" rows='8' cols='15' style='text-align: left; border:solid 1px black;' [(ngModel)]='newComment'></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button type='button' mat-raised-button color='primary' name='add-new-comment' (click)='addNewComment(newComment)' [disabled]=!userHasRole('Admin') || loading">Add Comment</button>
<mat-form-field>
  <textarea matInput readonly id='comments' name='comments' [disabled]="!userHasRole('Admin')" rows='8' cols='15' style='text-align: left; border:solid 1px black;' [ngModel]='comments'></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know does worked for you or not. Best wishes :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your second `textarea`, where you are using `[ngModel]="comments"`, change it to `[ngModel]="comments.toString()"`, or much better, use `*ngFor` to display comments.

Comment: Thanks rdr20 - 'comments.toString()' solved my problem.  I'll tinker with *ngFor as well and compare the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your declaration `this.comments: string[];`, you can not declare with `this` keyword. At the same time if you want to use string array then you have initiate the `comments` either like `comments: string[]=[];` or you can use constructor like below =>

```
comments: string[]=[];
constructor(){
  this.comments=[];
}
```

Then you have to use `[ngModel]="comments.toString()"` rather than `[ngModel]='comments'`.

**Note:** Here is the working demo code link [Stackblitz LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-textarea-mat-form-field-xm1gct?file=app%2Fform-field-theming-example.ts).

Comment: Thanks Linker for your response.  The code posted here was pseudo code and I munged the declarations (I'm not defining them in my actual code).  And, your suggestion for 'comments.toString()' was right on.  But, rdr20 beat you to it by a couple of hours.

Comment: And, the Stackblitz demo is awesome.  Thanks again.

Comment: no problem @rnoftz. I am glad to hair that your problem is solved . Best of luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `name="comments"` and `#comments='ngModel'` to your textarea element for ngModel to work